# Javascript To create a reverse sentence , what have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

to achieve

```
reverse("cool"); // "looc"


reverse("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") //"god yzal eht revo spmuj xof nworb kciuq ehT"

reverse("anna") // "anna"
```

My code is

```js
function reverse(sentence) {
  let reversedword = ""
  for (let i = sentence.length; i < 0; i = i-1) {
    reversedword = reversedword + sentence[i];
  }
  return reversedword;
}

console.log(
  reverse("cool")
)

console.log(
  reverse("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
)

console.log(
  reverse("anna")
)
```

The output of my code is empty `""`. Can someone help to fix my code so that I can understand?

Comment: The condition should be `i >= 0`.

Answer (score 3):

You should start the loop with `length-1`, and have the condition to `i>=0`.

Explanation:

You want to initialize your counter with the last character of your string. For example `hello` has `5` characters.

And then the last character's index is `4` (Strings as arrays, are "[zero-indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)"). So the first character (`h`) index is `0` and the last is `4`.

That's why you would initialize your array with `sentence.length-1`.

Then, you want your loop to continue while your index (`i`) is positive, or equals `0` which means that you reached the first character of your string.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#syntax

```js
function reverse(sentence) {
  let reversedword = ""
  for (let i = sentence.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
    reversedword = reversedword + sentence[i];
  }
  return reversedword;
}

console.log(reverse("cool"));
```

Answer (score 2):

there are two things which needs to be corrected

The condition in for loop is wrong which says i<0, it should be i > 0, since we will stop when i becomes zero as this is reverse loop.

Second thing is accessing the index, sentence[i], i will be out of bound index as javascript array starts from index 0.

Please find below as the corrected and working code

```js
function reverse(sentence) {
  let reversedword = ""
  for (let i = sentence.length; i > 0; i = i - 1) {
    reversedword = reversedword + sentence[i - 1];
  }
  return reversedword;
}

console.log(
  reverse("cool")
)

console.log(
  reverse("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
)

console.log(
  reverse("anna")
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just fix the for loop you'll get the desired out

```
function reverse(sentence){
    let reversedword = ""
        for ( let i = sentence.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i = i-1 ){
            reversedword =  reversedword + sentence[i];
        }
    return reversedword;
    }

console.log(reverse("cool")); // "looc"


console.log(reverse("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")) //"god yzal eht revo spmuj xof nworb kciuq ehT"

console.log(reverse("anna"));
```

Comment: This is exactly same as @Fcmam5's answer which is posted 15 mins earlier. Please delete it.